# Problem with permissions after upgrading

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, updates, root

A month or so ago I updated from 10.04 to 10.10, the problem is that after the update process programs that I had full control of no longer respond to me as a regular user,
and work normally only when I run them through the terminal using sudo.

Any idea how to fix that?
The programs that don't run normally are all the programs I installed before the distribution upgrade.

I used `sudo update-manager -d` to upgrade btw.

Comment: How and where did you install these programs? Did you install using a *.deb or did you compile from source?

Comment: We need to know the name of the programs, the user and group they execute under, if you had to reinstall them and what they do (communicate the hardware?)

Comment: all the programms i intalled were from the ubuntu software center except mysql that i used the alterantive installer for, and the user premmision for them is seems to be set to root,is there anyway to order the command line to reinstall all the programs? i'm pretty sure it will fix them,my theory is that the premmisions were set to root for all the programs that i had before the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reproduce this symptom with a fresh, new user account?

Comment: i tried with no succcess ,i opend a new user and it seems to work allright, oh and by the way since i wrote the question another thing started to happen when i log into my user i get a error regarding the fact ubuntu cannot authenticate my password

Comment: It looks like this is an upgrade-specific issue, then.  Have you tried resetting the permissions for one specific application's settings in your home directory?

Comment: sorry for the ignorance, since i'm quite new to Linux but how do i reset the premisions for a specific application?

Comment: well i got over the problem,sort off-i just formated and reinstalled.