# is there any kind of utility/protocol that can take premissions from root users?

Tags: 10.10, root

well i encountered a problem that i described in this question:
[Problem with permissions after upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13538/problem-with-permissions-after-upgrading)
and while speaking with my friend about it he mentioned some kind of protocol that can take
the permissions from root users he called it clinux but it think i misheard him because when i tried to google it, nothing came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux), but that almost certainly has nothing to do with the problem you encountered. It's not enabled by default in Ubuntu, you would have to install it yourself.

The problem also had nothing to do with "root users" -- your regular user account by definition was not a "root user", and you said running programs as root (with sudo) worked fine.

Comment: Actually just before I formatted I couldent run firefox or PDF viewer at all(probably some other things too,but didn't stay to check that out), and when I say couldn't run them I mean not with Audi and not as root user

Comment: Thx for the answer, but the wiki you directed me to states that ubuntu has SELinux starting from 8.04 realeas

Comment: @david25: It's _available_ in ubuntu, it is not installed or enabled by default.